# How to prove $\sum_{k=1}^{j} (2\sqrt k- \sqrt{k-1}-\sqrt{k+1}) \leq 1$?

Tags: summation, proof-writing

I tried doing it with induction, but I got stuck at the inductive step.

Comment: Seems like there will be a lot of telescoping; perhaps this can be exploited.

Comment: @User8128 when I exploit a telescoping summation, can I just list them out and cancel them visually, and that will be a satisfactory mathematical solution?

Comment: If you wanted to be absolutely rigorous, you could find a formula for the sum by writing out terms and cancelling but then prove that your suggested formula is true by induction.

Answer (score 0):

Note
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\sum_{k=1}^{j} (2\sqrt k- \sqrt{k-1}-\sqrt{k+1}) \\
&=&\sum_{k=1}^{j}\bigg[(\sqrt k- \sqrt{k+1})-(\sqrt{k-1}-\sqrt{k})\bigg] \\
&=&(\sqrt 1- \sqrt{2})-(\sqrt{0}-\sqrt{1})+(\sqrt 2- \sqrt{3})-(\sqrt{1}-\sqrt{2})+\cdots+(\sqrt j- \sqrt{j+1})-(\sqrt{j-1}-\sqrt{j})\\
&=&-(\sqrt{0}-\sqrt{1})+(\sqrt j- \sqrt{j+1})\\
&=&1+(\sqrt j- \sqrt{j+1})\\\\
&\le&1.
\end{eqnarray}